# Getting around onEdit()'s restrictions

Tags: javascript, triggers, google-sheets

I know that because onEdit() is a simple trigger, you aren't allowed to access other files.

My code requires that a different sheet be grabbed and stored (a sheet with a bunch of information), and then every time a user makes an edit on the sheet the script comes from, it runs the onEdit() code.

My original code won't work because the onEdit function is asking to retrieve that other sheet, which is a no-no.

However, couldn't I just have the other sheet (the one with info) declared stored as an array and then declared as a public variable (before the onEdit function), and then reference that in the onEdit function?

Thats what I thought I could do, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 0):

Besides the onEdit, set an installable onEdit trigger through Resources and try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this sheet will have to be copied by multiple users, and triggers through resources don't copy over (I have no idea why??)

Comment: Then build the trigger with script.

Comment: It appears triggers built in script will not work when authorization of another document is needed. For me, my code is grabbing and storing another sheet, and thus requires authorization.